# How to add data to intl.formatMessage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

How can I add data to intl.formatMessage on react-intl, an example: this is showing product.select.data

```
<FormattedMessage id={"product.select." + data} />
```

But, How can I do same with intl.formatMessage? this not working. this is showing product.select.undefined

```
props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "product.select." + data})
```

Comment: Please add useful title. Misleading

Answer (score 0):

This should work the same way, if data is defined, which does not seem to be the case in your second example. Maybe you should double-check if data is initialized correctly before your call to intl.formatMessage.